# What is the significance of '7 generations' in Luke’s account of Jesus's genealogy?

Tags: luke, gospels

Others have asked the significance of '14 generations' in Matthew's account, so it is relevant to a fuller understanding of the development of the gospels to note that Luke uses a different genealogy that is based on groups of seven generations, and to determine the significance of this sequence.

Luke had great men occur in multiples of 7 generations starting from Adam, with: Enoch at 7; Abraham at 21; David at 35; Jesus at 77.  He also had: Joseph at 42 and 70; Jesus (Jose) at 49.  To do this, he had to insert his own fictitious people into the Old Testament list: Kainan at 13; Admin at 28.

Comment: A good question but I didn't appreciate the matter-of-fact assertion that he inserted his own fictitious people. I think that is an unnecessary comment. It would be more tasteful in my opinion to at least say "it seems" or something to that effect.

Comment: Objectivity sometimes require a certain amount of matter-of-factness, otherwise what should be historical or theological discussions become ways to avoid actually saying anything. The biblical scholar, Joachim Jeremias says that the pre-exilic portion of Luke's genealogy is historically worthless, a far stronger statement than anything I have said, and then goes ahead and proves his case.

Comment: The main contention is the word 'he', not the word 'fictitious', as Niobius's answer indicates. The [NET translators notes](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Luke+3) have a useful summary of the difficulties with manuscript evidence here.

Comment: *He had to insert his own fictitious people into the Old Testament list: Kainan at 13.* - Luke is simply following the Septuagint.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the list, in groups of seven, as some translations have it:

> 1 Jesus - Joseph - Heli - Matthat - Levi - Melchi - Janna
>   
> 2 Joseph - Mattathiah - Amos - Nahum - Esli - Naggai - Maath
>   
> 3 Mattathiah - Semei - Joseph - Judah - Joannas - Rhesa - Zerubbabel
>   
> 4 Shealtiel - Neri - Melchi - Addi - Cosam - Elmodam - Er
>   
> 5 Jose - Eliezer - Jorim - Matthat - Levi - Simeon - Judah
>   
> 6 Joseph - Jonan - Eliakim - Melea - Menan - Mattathah - Nathan
>   
> 7 David - Jesse - Obed - Boaz - Salmon - Nahshon - Amminadab
>   
> 8 [*Admin*] - Ram - Hezron - Perez - Judah - Jacob - Isaac
>   
> 9 Abraham Terah - Nahor - Serug - Reu - Peleg - Eber 
>   
> 10 Shelah - [*Cainan*] - Arphaxad - Shem - Noah - Lamech - Methuselah
>   
> 11 Enoch - Jared - Mahalalel - Cainan - Enosh - Seth - Adam
>   
>  - God

"Admin" in group 8, is not well attested by Greek manuscripts.  Some translations choose to include him, and some don't.  In the words of Metzger, "Faced with a bewildering variety of readings, the Committee adopted what seems to be the least unsatisfactory form of the text".

"Cainan" in group 10 is better attested by manuscripts, though some early manuscripts do not include him.  However, it is more likely that the name "Cainan" was added than that it was removed - it would be very easy for a copyist copying a list of weird names to accidentally copy the same name twice (cf its undisputed occurrence in group 11).

Another argument against the inclusion of these two names is that the author of Luke knew the Old Testament well - it is difficult to see how he might have screwed up the genealogies between David and Adam, as these are easily found in Chronicles, and partially also Genesis (though "Cainan" is found in the LXX, though it was probably added either by a series of mistakes, or intentionally to create a 7+7+7+etc. symmetry - this was probably incorporated later into Luke by copyists).  Albeit, though less likely, it is possible that the changes went the other way.

In short, I think it is likely that the author of Luke intended to chronicle the actual genealogy of Jesus, and that later copyists added a couple of names to make the genealogy fit well in groups of seven, and possibly also to make the genealogy fit the Septuagint's genealogy in Gen 11.  These groups of seven probably are not intended have any symbolic value per se, but rather make the genealogy look "pretty" by making it into parallel groups with a "biblical" number.  It is unlikely that the genealogy was manufactured to have more prominent people at the beginning of each group - the Old Testament chronology already has Enoch seven generations from Adam, and the modifications to Luke's chronology bring only two prominent people (3 with Jesus) to the beginning of groups - and do so by placing a fictitious person at the beginning of a group (#8, Admin).  The duplication of names at the beginning of groups is not significant, as it would be even weirder if the beginning of groups did not duplicate names - many names are repeated often in this list (Jesus x2, Joseph x3, Matthat x2, Levi x2, Mattathiah x2 (in addition to Matthat and Mattathah), Judah x2).

Comment: Both Matthew and Luke include the great Zerubbabel, son of Shealtiel in their genealogies of Joseph and then Jesus. If the author of Luke knew the Old Testament well and intended to chronicle the actual genealogy of Jesus, then why does he give Neri as the father of Shealtiel and then go back through a line of commoners to David. Both Matthew and 1 Chronicles say that Zerubbabel was of the royal  line (although 1 Chron says that Shealtiel was only his uncle, while Matthew says his father). This line of commoners seems as much a theological construct as the '7 generations'.

Comment: I considered including the rest of my thoughts about the genealogies in my answer, but that wouldn't really be relevant to the question.  I believe that Jehoiachin was childless (cf Jer 22:30), and that the kingship passed from him to Shealtiel (as Matthew tracks the line of kings), but Shealtiel's father (or whoever 'adopted' him) was Neri.  Even if the Zerubbabel of 1 Chron 3 is the same person as Zerubbabel son of Shealtiel, this does not pose a problem: Luke was tracking the genealogy in a different way - e.g. biologically, legally, by inheritance/birthright, etc.

Comment: Matthew does not call Shealtiel Zerubbabel's father any more than he calls Abraham David's father (Mt 1:1) - all genealogies are not through direct biological lineage.  But either way, the issue of whether the genealogies themselves are historical is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Do we know whether the second Cainan (and Admin) is found on any manuscripts produced before the Common Era? This would indicate whether the author of Luke copied them or a late LXX redactor copied Luke.

Comment: The second Cainan is found in LXX manuscripts, but some think that the second Cainan was added to the LXX because scribes saw the name in Luke - thus it could have gone either way.  As far as I could tell, there is no evidence of Admin in the LXX or any other Old Testament manuscript - though it seems that particular part of Chronicles is missing from the available LXX manuscripts.  But there may be evidence of which I am not aware - my sources are the LXX, the BHS textual notes, and a few commentaries on Luke.

Comment: So, as I understand you, the earliest known reference to Admin is in Luke, and rather than Cainan "probably incorporated later into Luke by copyists," it is more likely to have been retrospectively incorporated later into a few manuscripts of the LXX by copyists?

Comment: Yes, the earliest known reference to Admin is Luke, as far as I know.  I honestly don't know whether it is more likely that the second Cainan appeared first in Luke or the LXX.  Some arguments for Cainan appearing first in Luke are that the copies of the LXX that we have are mostly from Christian sources, and that it is easier for a copyist to make a mistake in Luke (a mere list of names) than in Genesis (with descriptions of the lifespans of each person).  On the other hand, the LXX consistently tries to make the earth look older, so perhaps adding a generation is part of that ploy.

Comment: Why would LXX tries to make the earth look older? Due to scientific/historical evidence showing much older earth ;)?

Comment: No idea.  But I've heard the speculation that it was to conform it to the Egyptian worldview with an older earth (remembering that the LXX is supposed to have been translated in Alexandria).

Comment: *It was probably added either by a series of mistakes, or intentionally to create a 7+7+7+etc. symmetry.* - Neither, nor. Please read the eleventh chapter of Genesis, according to the Septuagint, and notice that from the birth of Noah's grandson, immediately after the Flood, to the birth of Abraham's father, Terah, there are exactly one thousand years.

Comment: @Niobius: *Some think that the second Cainan was added to the LXX because scribes saw the name in Luke.* - The Samaritan Pentateuch also includes Cainan, and Samaritans are not Christians.

Comment: @Lucian The document known as the Samaritan Pentateuch was used and copied by Christians from at least the second century AD.  As far as I can tell we have no copies of the Samaritan´s Pentateuch´s Genesis from before 1000 AD.  It is not unlikely that the document has been subjected to Christian influence.

Comment: @Niobius: Probably. But given the fact that no one modified the Vulgate (for instance) to reflect the same (or similar) textual variations in the Genesis chronologies, coupled with the fact that the same (dis)similarities seem to exist today (between the two texts) as have been noticed in the past (by patristic writers), as well as the fact that Christianity has (at least since Origen's *Hexapla*) a long-standing tradition of keeping-divergent-things-together-without-modifying-any-of-them (same as with the Four Gospels), I'd say the chances for that to have actually happened are rather small.

Comment: @Lucian It´s true that many Christian scribes were devoted to faithfully transmitting the text, but as I´m sure you know many of the significant textual variants in the gospels are there exactly because of scribal emendation - whether intentional for harmonization, or unintentional because they recalled the wording of a different account as they copied.  I do not believe it is far-fetched to think that one of the few copies of the Samaritan Pentateuch might have been changed by a tired or overzealous scribe without others transcribing other OT translations following suit.

Comment: @Niobius: That tired or overzealous Christian scribe would have to have lived prior to the fourth century, or would have to have had equally tired or overzealous companions who were willing to harmoniously modify ancient patristic descriptions of the Samaritan Pentateuch to correspond to his alterations.

Answer (score 0):

If the genealogy in Luke's Gospel is historical, we should not look for significance in the series of groups of seven ancestors, merely a surprising coincidence. So historicity, or otherwise, is the first thing to establish. Joachim Jeremias states in his book, *Jerusalem*, “...the custom of using the names of the twelve progenitors of the nation as personal names did not appear until after the exile ...When Luke cites the names of Joseph, Judah, Simeon, and Levi as descendants six through nine...this is an anachronism that proves the pre-exilic portion of Luke's genealogy to be historically worthless.” Raymond E. Brown states in his book *An Introduction to the New Testament* "While Luke's list may be less classically monarchical than Matthew's, there is little likelihood that either is strictly historical." Thus this strange series of coincidences could have a significance and we should seek to understand this significance.

Some of the groups of seven were contributed by the Yahwist in the Book of Genesis, some may well have been contributed by an LXX redactor/copyist(s) and some were certainly contributed by the author of *Luke*. Nevertheless it was the author of *Luke* who created the final genealogy with its long pattern of seven ancestors, and any meaning to the pattern can be found in the context of Luke's Gospel.

The number seven appears frequently in the Old Testament and particularly so in the Book of Revelation. Seven is the number of branches on the Menorah, and around the first century there were thought to be seven heavens. Generally, it appears to be a propitious number.

When the author of *Matthew* wrote a different but parallel genealogy for Jesus, he used a very similar pattern, this time using groups of fourteen, two times seven. He points this out in Matthew 1:17, implying that this was significant in proving that Jesus was destined for great things. I believe that the author of *Luke* also chose groups of seven generation to prove that Jesus was destined for great things.

Comment: Matthew lists three groups of fourteen (the double of 7). Highly doubtful that Luke's 77 generations are any less intentional.

Comment: Also, note that by excluding God and Christ from the list, we have 75 names, which coincides with the number of Gentile nations according to (Hellenistic) Hebrew tradition, based on Exodus 1:5 (LXX), quoted by Saint Stephen in Acts 7:14, which is also ascribed to Luke, the disciple of Paul, the Apostle to the Gentiles. Certainly, this cannot be all just a coincidence.